# Technical Architecture of Calypso, Jetpack, and Wordpress Blogs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rest, wp-calypso

Short Version: How does the new Calypso application (powering Wordpress.com) communicate with a privately hosted Wordpress blog via the Jetpack plugin?  i.e. Does Jetpack expose an API on my Wordpress hosting site?  Or is there other black magic going on.

Long Version: Calypso is a new javascript based application for managing blogs at the commercial hosting site Wordpress.com.  You can't use Calypso to directly manage blogs hosted privately with a copy of the open source Wordpress application.

However, there's a plugin for Wordpress [called Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/).  It's my understanding that, with the release of Calypso, it's now possible to manage content in your privately/personally hosted Wordpress blogs via the Wordpress.com/Calypso application **if** you have Jetpack installed locally.

What I want to know is: How does Jetpack do this?  I assume Jetpack exposes some sort of API on my private blog. Is that true?  Or is there some other black magic going on?

Does Wordpress.com/Calypso just sync regularly with my private blog?  Or are the updates in real time?

Context: I'm trying to understand the technical implicates of opening up my private blog to Calypso to ensure that features I program into wordpress plugins will play nice with whatever Jetpack is doing.  i.e. What does the Calypso`->`Jetpack`->`PHP Wordpress Application technical architecture look like?

There's multiple StackExchange sites I could ask this on -- but the Wordpress StackExchange seems focused on practical day-to-day use of Wordpress and not the technical implementation.  Since I'm a programmer, that makes Stack Overflow the next best bet.

Comment: i heard they were looking at developing wp on node sometime soon, it seems to be using node.js, but im waiting to see if they do actually develop fully onto node before doing anything serious with wp. But heres the git https://github.com/Automattic/wp-calypso

Comment: @David Useful background, thank you!  However, I'm interested in the technical architecture of the existing system.

Comment: Did you consider asking over at wordpress.org on the plugin page? Some of the authors work the forum.

Answer (score 2):

We had our Head of Technology write a detailed article on the architecture of this.

It could help clear some of your doubts regarding the technical architecture here.

[Technical Architecture of WordPress Blogs with Project Calypso](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/demystifying-project-calypso-and-wordpress-coms-new-architecture/)